# Xamarin.Forms HttpClient failed to connect error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I'm implementing JWT Auth with Xamarin forms. Now auth looks working from server side and I'm trying to test if it is working as expected on client side. My server app is running on local machine but emulator already configured to send traffic to my domain.

Here is my Xamarin.Forms Test method sending Request for testing:

```
async Task Test()
{
    try
    {
        var token = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("access_token");
        string url = "https://example.com:44330/account/testauth";
        using (var httppClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri(url),
                Headers =
                {
                    { "Authorization", $"Bearer {token}" }
                }
            };
            var response = await httppClient.SendAsync(request);

            string respStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //Do something
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         //handle exception
    }
}
```

After sending a request I'm getting an error `Failed to connect to example.com/52.202.22.6:44330`.

What configuration could be missed considering that WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync works fine for the same domain?

Comment: this is a networking problem.  Be sure your device can connect to your local server, check your firewall, be sure your local server can accept remote connections, etc.  Basic network debugging

Comment: @Jason as I sad above, the same domain working as expected via WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync

Comment: is it the same server?   running the same local service?

Comment: @Jason Yes, same server, same domain, same controller, but another method

Comment: Could it work now ?